# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '192.168.1.1'

Tags: python

an error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

```
def ports():
os.system("clear")
target = raw_input("Select a Target IP : ")
target = int(target)
os.system("nmap -O -Pn %s") % target
sys.exit();
```

any help please ?

Comment: '192.168.1.1' is not an integer. What did you expect? It's a string composed of 4 '.'-delimited integers. Just get rid of the `int(target)` and the code snippet will work fine.

Comment: It is not clear what question you are asking. Why are you calling `int()`?

Comment: An IP address is not an integer. What do you expect?

Comment: Just format your `target` as is, as a string.

Comment: when i remove the int(target)    os.system("nmap -O -Pn %s") % target
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: `os.system("nmap -O -Pn %s")` returns an int (the status exit code of the command) and then you try to use the `%` operator on an int and a string. You should change this line to `os.system("nmap -O -Pn %s" % target) `

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to convert the IP to `int`.
Instead, deal with it as a string.

Your real problem is with the line `os.system("nmap -O -Pn %s") % target` because `os.system()` returns an int (the status exit code of the command) and then you try to use the `%` operator on an int and a string. . It should be `os.system("nmap -O -Pn %s" % target)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a string to `os.system` but there is a [python-nmap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap) api  that will do what you want without any need for system calls and give you a lot more options, to scan a host it is as simple as:

```
import nmap
ip = "127.0.0.1"
scanner = nmap.PortScanner()
scanner.scan("-O -Pn {}".format(ip))
```

You can also easily do asynchronous scans:

```
import nmap
nma = nmap.PortScannerAsync()
def callback_result(host, scan_result):
    print('------------------')
    print(host, scan_result)

nma.scan(hosts='192.168.1.0/30', arguments='-sP', callback=callback_result)
while nma.still_scanning():
    print("Waiting >>>")
    nma.wait(2)   # you can do whatever you want but I choose to wait after the end of the scan
```

There are numerous examples [here](http://xael.org/pages/python-nmap-en.html). `os.system` is also not going to give you any output to parse, if you were doing  a system call you should be using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)